# How can I use Google or-tools on Android device?

Tags: python, android, or-tools

I have been trying to download it in the pip terminal and Jupyter Notebook because I need it for the University and I only own a Samsung Tab, but I finally gave up. Is there any way to use it (download or online)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, @JavierSerrano! I found this android app, and believe it may be useful to you: [How to Install Python and Jupyter Notebook onto an Android Device](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-python-and-jupyter-notebook-onto-an-android-device-900009df743f "How to Install Python and Jupyter Notebook onto an Android Device").

Comment: Just connect to a remote jupyter server or try something like Google Colab instead